# Qt: isSystemTrayAvailable() always crashes (Segfault) on Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop

Tags: qt, ubuntu-10.10

Why ideas why? has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Would it be interesting to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I made the mistake of calling that function before the initialization of the QApplication. Changing that order resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might me a long shot: I came across a similar problem when using another GUI related function of Qt (also under Ubuntu 10.10). I don't remember what function exactly it was, but it reproducibly crashed without any apparent reason. As it turns out, the reason was me not using the default Ubuntu theme. The one I used seemed to be buggy and when I changed back to the default one everything worked fine. Using the buggy one as root also seemed to work. So, if you're using a non default theme, you might give it a try.